# Access multiple instances in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, sql-server-2014-express, sql-server-2016-express

There are two instances of SQL Server installed on my PC.

[image: SQl server instance]

Version 11 and 13.

- for accessing version 11, I enter `.\` in a server name
- for accessing version 13, I enter `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB`

When it comes to IP address I enter 192.168.1.104 (my IP) in the server name and it directly opens SQL Server Express (v11)

So what I need to enter in server name so I can access SQL Server (v13) through IP address?

Comment: You need to find out the server ip for your MSSQL 13 . Then use that IP to connect to the desired server you want when you open SSMS.

Comment: MSSQL IP? what is it?  how it can be  different from my Machine ( IPv4 Address) IP

Comment: When you open SQL server, it will prompt you to enter a server IP or name to log into it. So you need to know the IP for your  localdb and use that IP to connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

[LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb) only works local via named pipes and does not support connections via TCP/IP, thus you won't be able to connect via IP-address.

Remark: There was a [declined feature request](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/775140/allow-localdb-access-through-tcpip-in-addition-to-named-pipes) some years ago.

Comment: so you mean there is no way to connect another instance are u sure?

Comment: Yes it's possible to connect multiple instances via TCP/IP in SSMS. But you can't connect the (LocalDB) instance via TCP/IP. If you have multiple SQL Express instances (not LocalDB's) on your computer you can connect to them via [Servername\Instancename] or [IPAdress\Instancename]. If you have only one SQL Express instance installed on your computer you can connect to it via IP, without providing the instance name.

Comment: Currently, I have SQL server 2016 so is there any way to change default instance?

Comment: And I have no idea why it is opening directly 11 version and not 13